# How to use a counter in a Postgresql function loop when generating a timestamp type for each iteration

Tags: postgresql-9.5

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserts_table_foo(startId INT,
                                         endId INT,
                                         stepTimeZone INT default 0,
                                         period INT default 0) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE

    nameVar TEXT;
    dateVar TIMESTAMP;

begin
    for idVar in startId..endId
        loop

            nameVar := md5(random()::text);
            dateVar :=
                    (now()::timestamp with time zone +
                     make_interval(hours := stepTimeZone) +
                     make_interval(days := period)
                        );

            period := period + 1;

            insert into foo(id, name, data) values (idVar, nameVar, dateVar);

        end loop;
end ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately, the *variable* -> **period**, does not work as intended.  I assumed that the counter would increase by 1 and each time, the ***date generation*** would be different, but in fact, the date turns out to be the same for the entire duration of the cycle.

How to make the date, for each iteration, be generated anew? This won't do here

```sql
generate_series ( TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2022-01-01', CURRENT_DATE, '1 day' )
```

because, you need to bet **100,000,000** records, in a table where the date field can be in the table in several places (**dateStart, dateEnd, startDateReg**, etc.) and are placed out of order. Therefore, I want to make a function that accepts a number of variables, according to which I can set the periods of the **generated values**, in this example, this is the **date and time**.

I would like to clearly see which variable the value comes into and also see the code for inserting this value into the table (that is, using the **INSERT into** entry .....)

What is the problem here and how could it be solved ?

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this. This can be done much more efficiently using `generate_series()` without a loop

Comment: And when there are 20 fields in the table, then also use generate_series()? It is convenient for me to see in the loop where the generated data is coming from and it is convenient to use the standard Insert to fill in a large number of records.

Comment: I created a trigger that wiill put date during isert row in a table. But it's not very convenient.